# Is it constexpr accessing base class member from intermediate derive class reference?

Tags: c++, constexpr

```
struct root
{
    int i = 0;
};

struct base: root{};
struct derive: base{};

constexpr derive d0;

int main()
{
    constexpr auto& r = static_cast<root const&>(d0);
    constexpr auto& b = static_cast<base const&>(r);
    constexpr auto& d = static_cast<derive const&>(r);

    static_assert(d0.i == 0, ""); // ok
    static_assert(r.i == 0, "");  // ok
    static_assert(b.i == 0, "");  // error in gcc
    static_assert(d.i == 0, "");  // ok
}
```

Clang accept the code above but gcc 7.2.0 compile with error below:

```
prog.cc:17:5: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
     static_assert(b.i == 0, "");
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
prog.cc:17:5: error: accessing value of 'd.derive::<anonymous>.base::<anonymous>' through a 'const base'
glvalue in a constant
```

It is not constexpr only if I access value 'i' via intermediate base.
Which compiler is correct?

Comment: What c++ specification are you compiling to? c++17?

Comment: compiled with both c++14 and c++17 also have the same result.

Comment: Interesting use case. I just want to chime in that I think it should probably be allowed by gcc, but perhaps they disallowed it because it's not guaranteed safe. (only `dynamic_cast` for downcasting is)

Comment: but in this case, the code is all inline and the actual type of the constructed object is visible to the compiler.

Comment: @AndyG Any undefined behaviour in expressions that are required to be constant expressions is ill-formed (diagnostic required), so that's not an argument.

Comment: GCC seems to accept the same code when you cast starting from d0. Clang simply accepts your code. Seems like a bug to me given that GCC tells you it can't access i, while it can if the same type is used starting from a different variable.

Answer (score -2):

`static_cast` from a base class to a derived class is UB, as is `static_cast` between non-standard-layout classes (those with virtual or non-public members or bases or multiple inheritance). So to make the above code well-defined you need public inheritance

```
struct base : public root{};
struct derive : public base{};
```

and you can only `static_cast` from `derive` to `base` or `root`, and from `base` to `root`, and not in the other direction.

Given GCC's usual semantics it probably "should" accept your code, but it also makes sense that it doesn't, since it relies on non-standard behavior.

Comment: Structs inherit publically by default, so that's not the problem.

Comment: `static_cast` from base to derived is well defined, as is `static_cast` between non-standard-layout classes.